# Redefining \bfseries command

Tags: macros, robust-commands

I am trying to redefine `\bfseries` to become a spacing-out command. The easiest way is to redefine it as `\so` macro from the `soul` package. The trouble is, `\so` takes an argument (and thus is analogous to `\textbf`).

Is there a good way to have a macro with the `\bfseries` syntax, which produces a letterspacing output (and also takes care of robustness)?

Comment: Have a look at the `soul` package manual, Section 7 "How the package works": "L e t t e r s p a c i n g , underlining, striking out and highlighting use the same kernel. It lets a word scanner run over the given argument, which inspects every
token." So, it needs to use an argument and is only really intended for shorter portions of text.

Comment: why take an existing command name and change its interface to take an argument? redefining something from bold to letterspace is reasonable but redefining the syntax can surely only lead to problems, why not use a new command name, or keep the existing syntax?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that would be easy. But I want to have a command that mimics `\bfseries` syntax, but produces the `\so` output. Actually, my question was misleading, correcting it now.

Comment: @MartinScharrer OK, that's fair enough. Though I do not intend to use it for long portions of text. I think there is a general problem here too: can we define a macro taking no argument like `\bfseries` via a macro that takes one?

Comment: @Jabot the answer to your most general question is no. But in practice you pretty well always have some context specific way of grabbing the text as a macro argument. Perhaps you should ask a specific question about the case you have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `\lsstyle` from the microtype package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

{\lsstyle some text letterspaced} some text not letterspaced

\end{document}
```

[image]

With xelatex you can do something like this (instead of redefining \lsstyle you can define your own command):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman} %needed for addfontfeature
\usepackage{microtype,ifxetex}
\ifxetex
 \AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand\lsstyle{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5}}}
\fi 
\begin{document}

{\lsstyle some text letterspaced} some text not letterspaced

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was aware of that possibility, but couldn't remember what was wrong with it. Now I do: letter spacing in `microtype` does not work with `xetex`. Still, as of now, this is the only solution.

Comment: I added an edit for xelatex.